# How to pass -F flag in curl request

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I am using this curl format. any one can help how it will pass in url or header in php. I don't know what mean of -F and how it will use in php.

```
curl -F 'client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>' \
     -F 'client_id=<CLIENT_ID>' \
     -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
     -F 'redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>' \
     -F 'code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE_FROM_STEP_2>'
      https://example.com/oauth/v2/token
```

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F